# How to reformat a Nested JSON and restructure using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

**My sample JSON , I would like to rebuild below json by  removing "Child:" Object**

```
{  
   "Child":{  
      "DeviceList":[  
         {  
            "Child":null,
            "DeviceId":"7405618",
            "Signal":"-90"
         },
         {  
            "Child":{  
               "DeviceList":[  
                  {  
                     "Child":{  
                        "DeviceList":[  
                           {  
                              "Child":null,
                              "DeviceId":"3276847",
                              "Signal":"-86"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     "DeviceId":"2293808",
                     "Signal":""
                  }
               ]
            },
            "DeviceId":"4915247",
            "Signal":"-90"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**New structure should look like this**

```
{  
   "DeviceList":[  
      {  
         "DeviceList":null,
         "DeviceId":"7405618",
         "Signal":"-90"
      },
      {  
         "DeviceList":[  
            {  
               "DeviceList":[  
                  {  
                     "DeviceList":null,
                     "DeviceId":"3276847",
                     "Signal":"-86"
                  }
               ],
               "DeviceId":"2293808",
               "Signal":""
            }
         ],
         "DeviceId":"4915247",
         "Signal":"-90"
      }
   ],
   "DeviceId":"4915247",
   "Signal":"-90"
}
```

I am looking for a nested recursive solution for a dynamic json tree structure where my JSON content will look like the sample provided.

Comment: you want to 'skip' `Child` key?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for moving `DeviceList` to the place of `Child`.

```js
var data = { Child: { DeviceList: [{ Child: null, DeviceId: "7405618", Signal: "-90" }, { Child: { DeviceList: [{ Child: { DeviceList: [{ Child: null, DeviceId: "3276847", Signal: "-86" }] }, DeviceId: "2293808", Signal: "" }] }, DeviceId: "4915247", Signal: "-90" }] } };

[data].forEach(function iter(a) {
    if ('Child' in a) {
        a.DeviceList = a.Child && a.Child.DeviceList;
        delete a.Child;
        if (Array.isArray(a.DeviceList)) {
            a.DeviceList.forEach(iter);
        }
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: you need to handle the case where "Child" is null.  it should still be replaced with "DeviceList" = null.